# How to rank a group in SAS by another group's ranks

Tags: sas, rank

I have two groups of firms, group A and group B, and I have a variable for each firm, call it beta.  Using proc rank, if I form 5 portfolios from group A's beta rankings, how can I assign firms from group B to group A's portfolios based on group B beta *values*, not group B's beta *rankings*?

Comment: You need to give more detail here, particularly include some example data and desired output, and preferably an attempt to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Define a format from the high/low beta values for the rankings for group A, and apply that format to the beta values for group b.